# Cmake rules not found in Included sub-cmake file

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

In a local `CMakeLists.txt` file, if i include another Cmake file, e.g.
`include(sub.cmake)` then `ninja` finds all rules. However, when including from a subdirectory, e.g. `include(subdir/sub.cmake)`, then it doesn't... Any idea why?

Comment: Looks like something is wrong in your CMake **code**.  You need to include that code into the question post (in form of [mcve]). See also [ask].

Comment: If the file was not found, then CMake would raise an error. So there's probably something wrong in `subdir/sub.cmake`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is no real help, but may be a helping hint. If you rename that `sub.cmake` in **another place** to `CMakeLists.txt`, does it compile then? Normally a sub-module or sub-file shall be makeable by itself and there are many reasons, why a project compiles - or not.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need not apologize for providing an answer. In fact, you should never do so because (1) it adds noise and (2) you needlessly open your answer to criticism. What you wrote would be better suited for a comment. Anyhow, you picked a difficult question to answer. The help pages contain some more hints on [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).